# Stop page from scrolling when intercepting key presses like space and arrows

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, scroll, prototypejs

I'm using JavaScript and Prototype and catching the key presses from the user. I successfully catch return, space and arrows with code like this:

```
Event.observe(window, "keyup", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case Event.KEY_RETURN:
    case Event.KEY_RIGHT:
    case 32:  // space
      // do something
      break;
  }
});
```

My problem is that spaces and arrow keep on scrolling the page. Is there a way to keep them from scrolling the page?

Comment: What's the best way to notify you using the "@" notation?  @J.Pablo or @JPablo?  Any idea of which works?

Comment: @brainjam Just copy and paste the user name. I think actually, SO only pays attention to the first part of the name up to the space, so @J. would work. Or, commenting on the question as you did does the trick.

Comment: @Alex, I think at least 3 characters are necessary.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020

Comment: I didn't even know SO would do something special with @; amazing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Prototype documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/stop):

> **Event.stop(event)**
>  Stops the event’s propagation and prevents its
>   default action from being triggered
>   eventually.

So adding `Event.stop(e);` before the `break;` should solve your problem.

Also, you should be doing this for the `keydown` event, because `keyup` is too late.

Comment: That didn't work in either Firefor nor Chrome. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @J.Pablo, I just realized you are only observing the keyup event.  Try observing the keydown and keypress events .. and using the Event.stop(e) there.  Otherwise, they're probably getting through to the browser.

Comment: keypress didn't work (it had no effect whatsoever, like if the event doesn't exist), keydown worked as I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to Stop default behavior of browser

Comment: Not sure that applies in this case

Comment: Andrew Barber: it does. in practice `preventDefault` is all you need and in theory seems to be the most correct solution to this problem, as the browser scrolling is a default behavior.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me (FF26). I used it in the keydown event.

Answer (score 6):

It's too late in `keyup` to prevent the default browser action. Do it in the `keydown` event instead and use Prototype's `Event.stop` method:

```
Event.observe(document, "keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case Event.KEY_RETURN:
    case Event.KEY_RIGHT:
    case 32:  // space
      // do something
      Event.stop(e);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Good insight that `keyup` is too late in the event life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault() works in Chrome.