# Prevent space and arrow keys scrolling web page?

Tags: javascript

I am overriding the behavior of the space bar and arrow keys when an element is focused to provide keyboard support on a web page. I need to disable the default behavior of those keys, which is to scroll the web page. I thought all that was needed to do this was to `return false` when you handled the event, but that didn't do the trick. I also added `preventDefault` yet it still scrolls the page in addition to performing my custom actions. What is the problem here?

```
document.getElementById('someID').onkeyup = function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var handled = false;

    if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40) { //up or down arrow
        //do something fun
        e.preventDefault();
        handled = true;
    }

    return !handled; //return false if the event was handled
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `onkeydown`?  When I tested the spacebar on a website, it seems like it jumped down when I pressed the key down, it didn't jump when I let the key up.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845071/stop-page-from-scrolling-when-intercepting-key-presses-like-space-and-arrows?rq=1

Comment: @Xero That was the problem!

Comment: Alright, you can accept the answer I just posted if you want.

Comment: My first thought after seeing the title was "Why would you do that?". Then I started reading the actual question and was like "oh ok".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the event to `onkeydown`.  By the time you reach `onkeyup` it's too late and the scrolling has already changed.

```
document.getElementById('someID').onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var handled = false;

    if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40) { //up or down arrow
        //do something fun
        e.preventDefault();
        handled = true;
    }

    return !handled; //return false if the event was handled
}
```